# 4th axiom neighbourhoods topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to study the equivalence between the definition with neighbourhoods and open sets from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_neighbourhoods) but I'm having trouble understanding an example.

Set of point $X = \{1,2,3\}$.
Set of open sets $O = \{\{1\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.
The generated neighbourhood filters are:
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
N_1 & = \{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\} \\
N_2 & = \{\{1,2,3\}\}\\
N_3 & = \{\{1,2,3\}\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

From this I can get back the open sets but this configuration doesn't meet the 4th axiom of neighbourhoods topology. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It *does* meet the fourth criterion: for $x=1$ we can always use $M=\{1\}$ and for other $x$ we use $M=\{1,2,3\}$. So I see nothing wrong.